# How do i change the picture/emblem of my android game ? - libGDX

Tags: android, image, libgdx

New to LibGDX. When i run my game on my android device it installs on the device with the default image of the android man :)

How would i go about changing this image to something of my choice ?

Is it on the android launcher ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that image in your android project res/drawable/drawable-xxxx folders. It is called ic_launcher. You can modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Open Manifest.xml file in Android project. Place your custom icon in res/drawable. And edit manifest file.